# Performance test with cache

Tags: performance, performance-testing

We have a service which is heavy CPU bound, it will do a lot of calculation for a given parameter, fornatulayely, the calculation result can be cached.

For example, a request `/data/{id}.png` will cost almost 2s for the first time, but we will cache the response for later user. When the cache is hit, the response time is 200ms(since we will do some light weight operation on the cache before response).

Now we want to provide a performance test report for this service expecilly for the max-concurrency and response time, but for a specified request(with a specified id paramter), there will be a huge difference between with and without cache. That means during the test, if we clear the cache, and use the random generated `id` parameter the report, there maybe too less cache can be hit, which result in a bad report. If we pre-cache most of the response and do the some test, the report may be looks well.

So I wonder how to reflect the real performance for this suitation?

Comment: This is unrelated, but have you looked into CloudFront? We also have an image server at work, and it’s really nice for helping reduce the amount of requests your server receives, and also they have tons of servers distributed around the world to speed up response times. It’s really nice. For example, one product that our image server powers is a simulcast auction system. At times, hundreds of peoples’ browsers may ask a new product photo simultaneously as a new item comes up for bid — with CloudFront, our server receives a single request and CloudFront handles the browser responses.

Comment: @Nate: Thanks we have the DNS acceleration service in production. While why I post this question is that I want to know the real performance ourselves.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry, I don’t know the answer to your actual question. I was just hoping the CloudFront thing would be helpful to you, since it was a game changer for us. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to know real performance you need to produce a **realistic load**. Not knowing the details of how will your service be used it is hard to come up with exact distributions of "cached" and "new" requests, however one thing is obvious: **well-behaved load test must represent real life application usage**, otherwise it doesn't make a lot of sense.

So [happy path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_path) testing would be something like:

1. Using anticipated distribution of "new" and "cached" requests
2. Using anticipated number of users of your system

This performance testing type is known as [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing). However I wouldn't stop at this stage as [load testing doesn't tell the full story](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough).

The next step would be putting your system under a prolonged load (i.e. overnight or weekend). You might also want to increase the load to be above the anticipated value. This testing type is called [Soak Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) and it is very good in discovering [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and problems with lacking resources like disk space over time

And finally you can check when (and how) you app is gonna break. Start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load until response time begins exceeding acceptable thresholds or errors start occurring (whatever comes the first). At this point you might also know if the application recovers back to normal when the load decreases. This testing type is known as [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) and most probably this way you will know your application [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)